# Problem with internet connection in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I have updated my ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04. And then I can not connect to wi-fi. I did not try anything yet. Who knows how can I solve this issue. Thank you!

Comment: There is almost no possible way for anyone to guess at what the problem might be without better understanding your situation. Could you edit your question to include: the brand and model of your computer, the output of `lspci`, whether your WiFi device is internal or a USB dongle, etc. This will make it much easier for someone to recognise possible issues and help you out.

Comment: The output of the "ip a" command and the contents of your netplan config file (/etc/netplan/*.yaml) may help you and others troubleshoot the problem.
As @Matigo mentioned above, output of the "lspci -v | grep -A 10 -i "Network Controller" is also important.

Comment: thanks, guys  i will try it. and if have more questions I will ask them too.)